UMVUE of $\mathbb{P}[X=x_0]$ where $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ is Poisson
I came up with this problem and tried to solve it myself. Please check my solution, I am a bit unsure it is correct because it says the UMVUE for the probability where $x_0>\text{sum of observations}$ is actually $0$. I'm also interested in how to manually verify that the final expression is indeed unbiased (i.e. without knowing that it was created by Rao-Blackwellization of an unbiased estimator). It's easy to verify in the $x_0=0$ case since we can use the MGF of $S$. $\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$
Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be a random sample from a $\mathrm{Po}(\lambda)$ distribution. What is the UMVUE of $p(x_0|\lambda)=\P[X=x_0]=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x_0}}{x_0!}?$
I got the answer $$T=\begin{cases}\binom{S}{x_0}(1/n)^{x_0}(1-1/n)^{S-x_0}&x_0\leqq S,\\0&x_0>S,\end{cases}$$where $S=\sum X_i$, via the following method:
Consider the rudimentary estimator $$W(X_1,\cdots,X_n)=\begin{cases}1&X_1=x_0,\\0&X_1\neq x_0.\end{cases}$$Then $\E[W]=\P[X_1=x_0]=p(x_0|\lambda)$, so $W$ is unbiased. The exponential family pmf of the Poisson distribution tells us that $$S=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$is a complete sufficient statistic for $\lambda$. Define the Rao-Blackwell estimator $$T=\E[W|S].$$Notice we can write $$S=\underbrace{X_1}_{\mathrm{Po}(\lambda)}+\underbrace{X_2+\cdots+X_n}_{\mathrm{Po}((n-1)\lambda)}.$$It is a well known property that if $A\sim\mathrm{Po}(\alpha),B\sim\mathrm{Po}(\beta)$, where both are independent, then the conditional distribution of $A$ given $A+B=s$ is $$A|_{A+B=s}\sim\mathrm{Bin}\left(s,\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}\right).$$It follows from Bayes' theorem. Applying this property to our problem, we have $$X_1|_{S}\sim\mathrm{Bin}(S,1/n).$$Finally, we have $$T=\E[W|S]=\P[X_1=x_0|S]=\begin{cases}\binom{S}{x_0}(1/n)^{x_0}(1-1/n)^{S-x_0}&x_0\leqq S,\\0&x_0>S.\end{cases}$$Since this unbiased estimator only depends on the data through a complete sufficient statistic, it is the UMVUE by Lehmann-Scheffe.

Is my solution correct?
If it is correct, can it be simplified?
How can we directly verify that this final estimator $T$ is unbiased without appealing to the fact that it is the Rao-Blackwellization of an unbiased estimator?


Testing some cases, it seems to work correctly and be unbiased. You can show $\sum\limits_{S=x_0}^\infty e^{-n\lambda}\frac{(n\lambda)^S}{S!} , {S \choose x_0}\frac{(n-1)^{S-x_0}}{n^S} $ $=e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{x_0}}{x_0!}\sum\limits_{S=x_0}^\infty e^{-(n-1)\lambda}\frac{((n-1)\lambda)^{S-x_0}}{(S-x_0)!} $ $= e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{x_0}}{x_0!}$ with some careful cancellation and factoring

There shouldn't be any doubt regarding the answer. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3268755/321264.
